# Htaccess and redirecting from https page to non https page

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I have a website where all URLs are rewritten to avoid seeing extensions and the original file name. So, in my htaccess, I have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^example-1$ filename_1.php
RewriteRule ^example-2$ filename_2.php
```

Now, I also have a few pages that I wanted to be only https and only http. So, let's say I want filename_1 to alwaysbe https and filename_2 to always be http. So, I have the following codes.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(filename_1)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
```

And

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(filename_2))\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
```

This is just and example but I actually have many files affected by those two rules.

Now, I thought it was working great until I noticed that when I am on an https page and I access a non https page, the url changes to show the actual file name. So, if I am on https://www.mywebsite.com/example-1 and I try to access example-2, the url changes to http://www.mywebsite.com/filename_2.php instead of http://www.mywebsite.com/example-2. And the same for going from http to https. (I am keeping it simple in those examples but the problem only arise with pages with variables in the url. Simple ones like www.mywebpage.com/homepage work just fine.)

So, I added this line of code:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(example-2)/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

So, it worked to go from https to http but then things just got crazy! I get redirect loops at certain https and non https page and I have no clue why! The thing is that I started by adding one page at a time to this new rule. And pages that I haven't even added yet give me some redirect loop. Then I try adding those pages but instead of https on, I used https off and it got even crazier.

So my question is what is a good way to have all the following perform harmoniously:
1. Rewrite all urls to custom ones
2. Having http and https page while keeping the custom urls and avoiding all redirect loops.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess in question.

Comment: All I have is a bunch of files names. I started the htaccess with: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on  and closed it with </IfModule> but everything else is a bunch of file names using the rules I wrote above. It worked fine except for that https/http transition.

Comment: Difficult to investigate/suggest without looking at all the code. If it is too big you can place it on pastebin and provide link here.